# Unity: save to asset (save currently trackend shaders into a shader variant manifest asset)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Unity has an Edit → Project Settings → Graphics section and a save to asset button in it.
How to call what this button does through c# scripts?
Thanks!

Maybe something has to do with the ShaderVariantCollection class, but I'm not sure

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This exact question was asked on Unity’s own forums. Make sure to look up your question before posting it on stackoverflow. [The question](https://answers.unity.com/questions/302313/how-to-save-an-asset.html)

Answer (score 0):

Save:

```
typeof(ShaderUtil).GetMethod("SaveCurrentShaderVariantCollection", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic).Invoke(null, new object[] { string path });
```

Clear:

```
typeof(ShaderUtil).GetMethod("ClearCurrentShaderVariantCollection", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic).Invoke(null, new object[0]);
```